# How to access node tree of a selected node group in python?

Tags: python

### Scenario:

[image: node groups]

I have these two node group instances "Test 1" and "Test 2" containing image textures. Now I would like to modify nodes inside of a selected node group in python.

To access the nodes inside a node group I have to know the name of the node group (e.g. "Material.Input 1" for node group "Test 1"):

```
img_node = bpy.data.node_groups ["Material.Input 1"].nodes ["Image Texture 1"]
```

But I would like to do this dynamically using the selected node group like this:

```
active_node = context.active_node
# active_node.name: Group.003
# active_node.group: Test 1
img_node = bpy.data.node_groups [active_node.???].nodes ["Image Texture 1"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, to get the currently **active** node, you can use

```
currNode = context.active_node
```

from within an addon / Operator (which I suppose you're doing, otherwise there would be no bpy.context.selected_nodes). From the Python Console, getting the currently active node in the compositing tree would be

```
currNode = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.active
```

From there, you can use

```
currNode.id_data
```

to retrieve the tree this node lives in. This also works in Material Node Trees. To retrieve the **materials** (remember it could theoretical be more than one material using the same node tree) you can to:

```
print ([x for x in D.materials if x.node_tree == currNode.id_data])
```

So in your example:

```
# get a node first
x = D.node_groups['NodeGroup'].nodes['Group Input']

# now get the tree of this node (which is the node group)
x.id_data    # this gives you 'Node Group' again
```

### Edit: Find the node tree of a group

After the question has been rephrased, this solution would be smarter: Node groups simply have an own Node Tree themselves. You can think of it like:

```
ShaderNodeTree.nodes[someGroup].node_tree.nodes[someOtherGroup].node_tree.nodes.thisCanGoOnForever
```

So in your case:

```
active_node = context.active_node
# active_node.name: Group.003
# active_node.group: Test 1

# find an image node in the group node tree
# groups have their own node tree to collect nodes
img_node = active_node.node_tree.nodes.get("Image Texture 1")
```

If the Image Texture named "Image Texture 1" exists, img_node will be the object. Otherwise, img_node will be None.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately calling currNode.getNodeTree() throws an error (object has no attribute "getNodeTree"). Furthermore this function doesn't appear in the blender documentation.

Comment: @Steffen DOH, must be an addon which adds that method. I'll investigate and report back.

Comment: @Steffen OK, found it, it's part of the Animation Nodes addon. I'll adapt the answer later

Comment: @Steffen ok, answer is updated. there is an id_data property that gives you the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks again for the advice! I did some tests but didn't find the solution yet. I updated my question a little bit to make things clearer, maybe you have an idea...

Comment: @Steffen edited my answer again. Basically, you're looking in the opposite direction than what I thought you would. Which is easier: Each Node group has its own node tree that you can call. Even if groups are inside of groups, see my examples in the updated answer

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! I wasn't aware that `context.active_node` returns an object of type `ShaderGroupNode`! I only read the documentation of `ShaderNode` instead...